# Submitting a job to qsub remotely

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, qsub

I would like to submit jobs to a computing cluster remotely. Normally to submit a job to the cluster, I have to login to my account using SSH and then issue this command `qsub script.sh`. I was wondering if there is a trick which allows me to submit remotely without having to login to my account and then submit from there.

Comment: I think this migt be [out of topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as it does not seem to be related to programming directly. Other Stack Exchange sites, like [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) might be more suitable and your question would probably get more attention, and answers, there. To answer your question, though, you could just do `cat /your/job/script.sh | ssh clusterserver 'cat > /tmp/foo.sh && qsub /tmp/foo.sh'`, in case your workstation runs Linux/BSD/UNIX.